# Execute request on ZOO Project WPS Client gives Response:400 (Bad Request)

Tags: http-post, wpsclient, zoo-project

I made the zoo-client-demo WPS Client strictly according to the [ZOO WPS Client Documentation][1]. The only changes I made were that I changed the request type of GetCapabilities and DescribeProcess to 'GET' instead of 'POST' that was initially defined, the version number to 2.0.0, the Identifier name to 'AddPy' (a test process I wrote) and the debug flag to true. I have also added logging statements to track the flow of the code.

I am working on Windows 10 and am using IIS to run the WPS.

On checking the console (Chrome developer tools) I see the following: (... has been used hide multiple lines where the same error caused an issue; I can supply that later if needed)

```
first.js:52 execute called from first.js
first-app.js:54 Execute called from first-app.js
zoo.js:344 execute called in zoo.js
zoo.js:207 convertParams called in zoo.js
zoo.js:210 ======== Execute AddPy
zoo.js:211 {identifier: "AddPy", dataInputs: Array(2), dataOutputs: Array(1), type: "POST", success: ƒ, …}
zoo.js:227 zoo_request_params from convertParams of zoo.js
zoo.js:228 {request: "Execute", service: "WPS", version: "2.0.0", Identifier: "AddPy", DataInputs: Array(2), …}
zoo.js:230 has ResponseDocument false
zoo.js:234 has Mode false
zoo.js:247 convertParams returned zoo_request_params
value:
zoo.js:248 {request: "Execute", service: "WPS", version: "2.0.0", Identifier: "AddPy", DataInputs: Array(2), …}
zoo.js:369 request called in zoo.js
zoo.js:266 buildRequest called in zoo.js
zoo.js:269 ======== REQUEST method=POST
zoo.js:270 {request: "Execute", service: "WPS", version: "2.0.0", Identifier: "AddPy", DataInputs: Array(2), …}DataInputs: (2) [{…}, {…}]DataOutputs: [{…}]Identifier: "AddPy"language: "en-US"request: "Execute"service: "WPS"version: "2.0.0"__proto__: Object
wps-payload.js:81 getPayload called in wps-payload
wps-payload.js:212 getPayload_Execute called from wps-payload.js
wps-payload.js:285 ==== OUTPUTS ====
wps-payload.js:289 {identifier: "Sum", type: "resultDocument"}identifier: "Sum"is_resultDocument: truetype: "resultDocument"__proto__: Object
wps-payload.js:296 Returned templates[id].render(params)
value:
wps-payload.js:297 <wps:Execute
    xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/2.0"
    xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/2.0"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/2.0 ../wps.xsd"

    service="WPS"
    version="2.0.0"
    response="document"
    mode="sync">

    <ows:Identifier>AddPy</ows:Identifier>
        <wps:Input id="first_number">
            <wps:Data>21</wps:Data>
        </wps:Input>
        <wps:Input id="second_number">
            <wps:Data>21</wps:Data>
        </wps:Input>
      <wps:Output id="Sum" transmission="value" />
</wps:Execute>
zoo.js:288 ======== POST PAYLOAD ========
zoo.js:289 <wps:Execute
    xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/2.0"
    xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/2.0"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/2.0 ../wps.xsd"

    service="WPS"
    version="2.0.0"
    response="document"
    mode="sync">

    <ows:Identifier>AddPy</ows:Identifier>
        <wps:Input id="first_number">
            <wps:Data>21</wps:Data>
        </wps:Input>
        <wps:Input id="second_number">
            <wps:Data>21</wps:Data>
        </wps:Input>
      <wps:Output id="Sum" transmission="value" />
</wps:Execute>
zoo.js:290 {request: "Execute", service: "WPS", version: "2.0.0", Identifier: "AddPy", DataInputs: Array(2), …}
zoo.js:299 ajax url: http://localhost/cgi-bin/zoo_loader.cgi
zoo.js:301 buildRequest returned {"url":url,"headers": headers,"data": payload,"type":type}
values:
zoo.js:302 {url: "http://localhost/cgi-bin/zoo_loader.cgi", headers: {…}, data: "<wps:Execute↵  xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wp…t id="Sum" transmission="value" />↵</wps:Execute>", type: "POST"}
jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4 OPTIONS http://localhost/cgi-bin/zoo_loader.cgi 400 (Bad request)
send @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
ZooProcess.request @ zoo.js:374
ZooProcess.execute @ zoo.js:346
...
jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4 OPTIONS http://localhost/cgi-bin/zoo_loader.cgi 400 (Bad request)
send @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
ZooProcess.request @ zoo.js:374
ZooProcess.execute @ zoo.js:346
...
index.html:1 Failed to load http://localhost/cgi-bin/zoo_loader.cgi: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400.
zoo.js:377 ALWAYS
zoo.js:383 ======== ERROR ========
xml2json.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined
    at w (xml2json.min.js:1)
    at X2JS.xml2json (xml2json.min.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (zoo.js:385)
    at j (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
w @ xml2json.min.js:1
X2JS.xml2json @ xml2json.min.js:1
...
```

It seems that there is some error when the request type is set to 'POST' as I can only see the base URL (`http://localhost/cgi-bin/zoo_loader.cgi`) being sent in the error response.

Here is the code for my first.js (keeping only the relevant portions):

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'assets/js',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min',
        hogan: 'lib/hogan/hogan-3.0.2',
        xml2json: 'lib/xml2json/xml2json.min',
        queryString: 'lib/query-string/query-string',
        wpsPayloads: 'lib/zoo/payloads',
        wpsPayload: 'lib/zoo/wps-payload',
        utils: 'lib/zoo/utils',
        zoo: 'lib/zoo/zoo',
        domReady: 'lib/domReady',
        app: 'first-app',
    },
    shim: {
        wpsPayloads: {
            deps: ['hogan'],
        },
        wpsPayload: {
            deps: ['wpsPayloads'],
            exports: 'wpsPayload',
        },
        hogan: {
            exports: 'Hogan',
        },
        xml2json: {
          exports: "X2JS",
        },
        queryString: {
            exports: 'queryString',
        },
    },
});

requirejs.config({
    config: {
        app: {
            url: 'http://localhost/cgi-bin/zoo_loader.cgi',
            delay: 2000,
        }
    }
});

require(['domReady', 'app'], function(domReady, app) {
    domReady(function() {
        console.log("execute called from first.js");
        app.execute();

    });
});
```

and here is the code for first-app.js (again, only the relevant portions):

```
define([
    'module','zoo','wpsPayload'
], function(module, ZooProcess, wpsPayload) {

    console.log("myZooObject initialized in first-app.js");
    var myZooObject = new ZooProcess(
        {
        url: module.config().url,
        delay: module.config().delay,
    });

    var execute_app = function() {
        console.log("Execute called from first-app.js");
        myZooObject.execute({
           identifier: "AddPy",
           dataInputs: [{"identifier":"first_number", "value":21},{"identifier":"second_number", "value":21}],
           dataOutputs: [{"identifier":"Sum","type":"resultDocument"}],
           type: 'POST',
           success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log("Data returned by Execute of first-app.js");
           },
           error: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                console.log("ERROR returned by Execute of first-app.js!");
           }
        });
    }

    // Return public methods
    return {
        execute: execute_app,
    };
});
```

The code for the rest of the elements is the same as that provided by wps-client on following the documentation. Is there something that I missed or a possible workaround? I should add that I am not too sure if this is an error in code or in the server (IIS) configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I was trying to run the program by executing the HTML script by double-clicking it instead of typing the URL on the browser. Executing by typing the required URL seems to have corrected the error.